# Keep camera from rotating around relative z-axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create camera movement that mimics the behavior of the unity scene editor where you can perform a spherical rotation around the scene with 2d mouse movement. So far the camera is rotating correctly given x or y movement, but dragging diagonally causes the camera to rotate around its relative z-axis until it gets locked. I cannot force the camera to look at the origin relative to world up because then it cannot rotate upside-down

Here is the script that I've attached to the camera

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 startingPosition;
    Vector2 mousePosition;
    Vector3 orthogonalCameraVector;
    float degreesPerUnitWidth = 180f / Screen.width;
    float degreesPerUnitHeight = 180f / Screen.height;
    float cameraRadius = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraRadius);
        transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero);
        orthogonalCameraVector = -Vector3.left;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            var input = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x ,Input.mousePosition.y);

            startingPosition = mousePosition;
            var mouseDelta = startingPosition - input;

            var xzDegrees = -mouseDelta.y * degreesPerUnitHeight;
            var xzRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(xzDegrees, orthogonalCameraVector); // rotate about the relative x-z plane
            var yRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseDelta.x * degreesPerUnitWidth, Vector3.up); // rotate about the world y-axis
            var rotation = xzRotation * yRotation;
            orthogonalCameraVector = rotation * orthogonalCameraVector;
            transform.position = rotation * transform.position;
            transform.rotation = rotation * transform.rotation;
            mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the `orthogonalCamerVector` only needed to be rotated about the y-axis because I wanted to keep it parallel with the xz-plane. I then applied this rotation to the `orthogonalCamerVector` before rotating the `transform` so it would always be rotating about a fixed plane so it looks something like this:

```cs
        var xzDegrees = -mouseDelta.y * degreesPerUnitHeight;
        var yRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseDelta.x * degreesPerUnitWidth, Vector3.up); // rotate about the world y-axis
        orthogonalCameraVector = yRotation * orthogonalCameraVector;
        var xzRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(xzDegrees, orthogonalCameraVector); // rotate about the relative x-z plane
        var rotation = xzRotation * yRotation;
        transform.position = rotation * transform.position;
        transform.rotation = rotation * transform.rotation;
```